# Have I well understood the difference between present continuous and going to in a future event

Tags: future-tense

Here is the situation

I am my own boss, and I want to take some vacation next week

What will I say:

"I **am taking** next week off" or "I **am going to** take next week off"

I think the second  one is better  because as I am my own boss it is not an arrangement with somebody else I **am only involved in that decision** and it is only an intention .

Now imagine that I **already booked a hotel**  for this vacation , I will say "I am taking the next week off"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is less difference between your two examples than you think.

Both could be used in the situation you describe. Perhaps saying "I'm taking next week off." suggests you are slightly more certain. But Native speakers would use both.

If someone says "I'm taking next week off" it doesn't imply that they have booked a hotel. Similarly, if they say "I'm going to..." It doesn't imply that they haven't booked a hotel.

If you are really unsure of your plans, I'd use "I'm hoping to take ..." or "I want to take..." rather than "I'm going to".

Comment: is "already booked" possible as you answered using present perfect

Comment: present perfect is the natural tense to use with "already". You can say I already booked, but "I've already booked" matches the meaning with the tense. There is also a dialect difference. UK English tends to prefer present perfect in this situation.